# adobe flex htmltext property

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, html-lists

how do i get an ordered list using htmltext property of Text component?
I tried using this:

`<ol><li>item</li><li>item</li></ol>`

but it rendered like an unordered list. can any one suggest a solution?

Thanks
Anji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. This über guy extended the Text / TextArea comoponent, check it out!

Demo:
http://stephen-m.appspot.com/htmlFilter

Project page:
http://code.google.com/p/flex-htmlfilter/

Answer (score 0):

is not supported.
Just the -li- tag will be processed. And as the result, you get an unordered list.

There is no way

BR
Frank

Comment: there is a custom component. see answer above.